# Nextjs not displaying the image send from backend?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

{
"id": 89,
"url": "https://homez.d.deli.work/storage/89/IMG_٢٠٢١٠٢٠٩_٢٢٤٤٠٠.jpg",
"preview": "https://homez.d.deli.work/storage/89/IMG_٢٠٢١٠٢٠٩_٢٢٤٤٠٠.jpg",
"name": "IMG_٢٠٢١٠٢٠٩_٢٢٤٤٠٠",
"file_name": "IMG_٢٠٢١٠٢٠٩_٢٢٤٤٠٠.jpg",
}

here is the object send from the backend, image url is shown normally in the browser but not shown in the code `<Image src={meal?.images[0]?.preview || placehoderImage} alt="meal img"/>`
and the alt tag is shown instead, I don't know why I think becuase image name contains some non-english numbers. how can i handle this?

Comment: Do you have some error when loading image in network tab in dev tools?

Comment: Try encoding the URI like: `src={encodeURI(meal?.images?.[0]?.preview) || placeholderImage}`. Not sure if it will work.

Comment: @Wraithy, No I have no erros at all

Comment: @brc-dd, Thank you very much, It worked however I don't understand excatly what `encodeURI` did to the url

Comment: @AbdelrhmanGad Refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI, it basically changed your UTF-8 characters to equivalent escape sequences so that the resultant URL can be represented using ASCII characters only.

Comment: @brc-dd Okay now i get it,thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)